# C++ qt programming, windows and linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

If I write a program in C++ using Qt on windows, can I run the program on Linux (not run .exe, but use the source code)?

P.S. I don't mean using wine

Comment: Yes, you can. Just recompile on Linux.

Comment: Yes, since Qt is cross-platform framework, so all you have to do is to just recompile it on your Linux machine.

Comment: Have you read the tagwiki?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use just the Qt framework, without any platform specific code, you will be able to compile that code on each platform. You will not, for example, be able to run the compiled binary from one platform directly on another, such as the Windows executable on Linux.

Comment: Wrong, of course you can run windows code directly on linux, using `wine`.

Comment: @user1095108 You can **sometimes** run it using wine.

Comment: @user1095108, well yes you could use wine, though you could also include emulation or virtualisation, but it's not really the point here, is it?!

Comment: The point is, that `.exe` files can be run seamlessly under `linux`, even without explicitly invoking `wine`, if the dependencies are met.